# Бесконечный таймер setTimeout в nodejs

Tags: node.js, таймер, settimeout

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой при использовании setTimeout в node.js.

По непонятной мне причине в windows 2012 и 2007 r2 (возможно и в других версиях) запущенный в консоле скрипт с использованием рекурсивного setTimeout (бесконечный таймер) просто перестает выполнятся (как будто у него завод кончается).

При этом в unix системах тот же скрипт работает без каких-либо остановок.

1. В чем может быть причина, в какую сторону копать?
2. Как можно отследить эту остановку и автоматически перезапустить работу таймера не перезапуская всю консоль со скриптом целиком?

Я попробовал отловить момент, когда таймер остановится, путем мониторинга переменной в которой записывал дату unixtime и проверкой на опережение текущей даты от даты в переменной больше чем на N минут. И после этого обнаружения зависания делал новый вызов функции с таймером. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что в какой-то момент при таком использовании начинало крутиться 2 одинаковых скрипто-таймера (что делать не нужно), первый который повис, сам отвисал внезапно. Хотя если не делать повторный запуск нового таймера, то старый ни когда не отвисал, ни через 5 минут, ни через 2 часа.

Следовательно 3 вопрос: Как тормознуть таймер-дубликат, и оставить только 1 работающий?

Либо можете посоветовать какой-то алгоритм без использования setTimeout или библиотеку которая позволит сделать управляемый таймер с возможностью изменения времени между циклами и принудительной остановкой/запуском этого таймера.

Comment: По поводу первых двух вопросов не знаю, но почему не делать `clearTimeout`, а потом новый таймаут?

Comment: Ноду обновить не пробовали?

Comment: @MedvedevDev, делается перед каждым циклом. Но не помогает. Видать в какой то момент он или запаздывает с очисткой или что-то еще.

Comment: @PavelMayorov версия ноды не влияет, пробовал и на 8.x и на 9.3 текущей, проблема одна и таже.